# Pointing domains to a Main Wordpress sites pages

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have a particular client that is requiring what is essentially 31 sites. There is one main site e.g. mydriving.com. Then there are 30 other sites that are the particular sectors e.g. mytruckdriving.com, myvandriving.com, mycardriving.com etc (these will not be sub-domains).

Content will differ slightly and there is the possibility of e-commerce adding on all sites, which makes things a little more upkeep.

It will be built in Wordpress, and I have previously had experience with setting up an e-commerce multisite, with each seperate domain pointing to the same IP for the multisite, then a domain-mapping tool handling the redirects. This was fine for 4 sites but 30 will be a lot of upkeep.

The client did not like the sound of having 31 different admin panels for what is essentially slight changes in content, as well with the fact each site would share some content (footer/about etc).

I'm not sure what would be a better solutions. One thing I was possibly thinking was having each domain point at a particular page e.g. mytruckdriving.com -> mydriving.com/truckdriving. However I am not sure how correct this would be and whether or not it is discouraged to redirect domains to particular pages in a Site.

If anyone has any tips on the best direction or good practices that would be most appreciated.

Many thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

If there is 31 different sites with 31 different iterations (whether small or large), the nature of the beast is that you have a 31 different sites to maintain...no matter what way you slice it.

I like your multisite idea...what if with your domain mapping tool you map all of those domains to point to the same "site" and within the theme files you put the logic for adjusting content based on the current domain. Would take some custom php work, but should be doable.